# Remove all occurence of anchor tags from a string, while preserving their inner text nodes

Tags: jquery, string, strip

I have an HTML string. I'd like to transform this:

```
<table >
  <tr>
      <td><a href="/link.html" onclick="javascript:aFunction()">some text</a></td>
      <td><a href="/anotherlink.html">some more text</a></td>           
  </tr>
</table>
```

Into this:

```
<table >
  <tr>
      <td>some text</td>
      <td>some more text</td>           
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery 1.4+, you can pass a function to [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/), like this:

```
​$("table a")​.replaceWith(function() { return this.innerHTML; });​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/f87z7/).

If you literally have a string, and not elements, it would look like this:

```
var html = '<table>...{rest of string}...</table>';
var o=$(html).find('a').replaceWith(function(){ return this.innerHTML; }).end();​
```

[You can try that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/f87z7/1/).

Comment: +1 For the edit to use innerHTML.  Would be ideal if the code sample factored in the fact that he has an HTML string, not a DOM to work with.

Comment: @Josh - Good point and catch on the question, added a string version above :)

Comment: this question is from my lack of jquery prowess but i am trying to manipulate a string of html (var htmlstr = '<table><tr>...';)

Comment: @user449996 - See the second example and demo (refresh the page if you don't see them), it shows how to do it with a string as well.  If you don't want elements at the end, you still want a string, here's a version doing that: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/f87z7/2/

Comment: Wow! having hard time keeping up with the responses :-) Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$('td a').each(function(){
   $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
});
```

Comment: sorry for the silly question as i don't understand jquery well. What i have is an actual string (var htmlstr = '<table>....';). How would this solution be used for the string htmlstr?